# Illustrator: how to construct curved and bent triangles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm looking to recreate this effect in Illustrator but cannot find the right tool to do the job. Any help in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- Draw a circle
- Duplicate it
- use the **Pathfinder Panel** to intersect them
- **Reflect** a copy
- Draw a rectangle over the part you want removed.
- Use the **Shape Builder Tool** (holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>
  key) to remove what you don't want, then without Option/alt to join
  the other parts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Create a circle
- Make a copy and offset to the right
- Pathfinder > Minus front
- Delete the lower anchor with the Direct Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Make it green
- Duplicate the green shape, flip it around and position as needed

[image]